Live Activity works in simulator, but not on iPhone
I have developed a feature using Live Activity. It works correctly on the simulator, but when I run the same code on my real iPhones, the feature doesn't work as expected.
When calling the function to start the Live Activity, the console indicates success. However, the Live Activity does not appear on the Lock Screen of the physical devices. It only shows up when running in the simulator. I need it to work on the physical device.
Setup:

React Native version: 0.75.4
Xcode version: 16.0

Devices:

iPhone XS Max on iOS 18.0.1
iPhone 13 on iOS 18.0.1

Permissions Configured: I have enabled relevant permissions like Background Modes and Remote Notifications.



Are you testing against the same type of devices in the simulator? Neither physical device that you're testing with has a dynamic island or always on display, which makes testing the live activity harder, so would be good to clarify that the issue is definitely caused by physical device vs simulator and not by different device being simulated.

You should also include the code for your live activity in your question (and the code used to start the live activity) to make sure that there's no issue there.
